# python sqlite command in path

Tags: 10.04, python

I am installing a program, and one of the requirements is to have python sqlite2 installed.
I check this by:

```
$ python -c "import sqlite3"
```

The second requirement is:
"Additionally you must have the `sqlite3` command on your path. This can usually be found in a package called `sqlite` or `sqlite3`."

Can someone explain what I should do? Where and how to set that path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install sqlite3 with the command

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

The `sqlite3` command will be on your path after install, no need to do anything else. You can verify this by simply entering

```
sqlite3 --version
```

in your terminal.